# How do I calculate the characteristic function of the random variable $Z$?

Tags: probability

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and each has a density $f(u) = u/2$ when $u$ is from $(0,2)$ otherwise $f(u) = 0$. I should calculate the characteristic function of the random variable $X$ and use it to calculate
characteristic function of a random variable $Z = 2X - Y$.
Thank you for every attack.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are IID so let $\varphi(t)=E[e^{itX}]=E[e^{itY}]$ be the common characteristic function.

Then the characteristic function of $2X-Y$ is, using their independence, is given by

$$
E[e^{it(2X-Y)}]=E[e^{it2X}e^{-itY}]=E[e^{it2X}]E[e^{-itY}]=\varphi(2t)\varphi(-t)
$$

Now, we find $\varphi(t)$, using integration by parts:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(t) 
&=&
E[e^{itX}]\\ 
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{x=2} e^{itx}\frac{x}{2} dx\\
&=&
\frac{e^{itx}}{it}\frac{x}{2}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=2}-\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\frac{e^{itx}}{it}\frac{dx}{2}\\
&=& 
\frac{e^{2it}}{it}-\frac{e^{itx}}{2(it)^2}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=2}\\
&=& 
\frac{e^{2it}}{it}-\frac{e^{2it}}{2(it)^2}+\frac{1}{2(it)^2}\\
&=&
\frac{-1+e^{2it}(1-2it)}{2t^2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, the characteristic function of $2X-Y$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(2t) \varphi(-t) 
&=&
\left(\frac{-1+e^{4it}(1-4it)}{8t^2}\right)\left(\frac{-1+e^{-2it}(1+2it)}{2t^2}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand so much better.